# # symbol in path of file in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8

I have many folders in Virtual Directory, many of them have `#` in theirs name,
when something like this be requested from IIS, it will return 404 error,
folder name is `John^Rezaei^^#SM 183217` and it seems it be separated in LOG file like:

```
2019-08-11 10:29:31 ::1 GET /web/virtuald/Study/John^Rezaei^^ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/75.0.3770.142+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 690
```

from `#` to end is ignored, mean `/web/virtuald/Study/John^Rezaei^^` requested not `/web/virtuald/Study/John^Rezaei^^#SM 183217/im00001.jpg`.

even by adding below config nothing changed:

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the # is the special character in the url part. The data behind the # will be regards as the querystring.

So you should use %23 to replace the "#".

So the url for the vitual path, you should use is `John%5ERezaei%5E%5E%23SM%20183217`.

More detals, you could refer to below image:

[image]

Comment: I should use `%23` to replace the `#`, probably you mean I should have something like `UrlRewrite` module to replace or something else? can you please clarify how.

Comment: I mean you need to you use %23 to replace the # in the browser address bar or let the client side know it should use %23 instead of #. Url rewrite will also not modify the # to %23.

Comment: Great, Just replacing it, from what I am generating and sending Url address in BE then I can replace `#` with `%23`. something like `strUrl.Replace("#","%23")`